# Python signal for timeout doesn't actually stop the code that's taking too long

Tags: python, timeout, signals, sage

I'd like to do some computations in Python (actually in Sage, which is based on Python), but if they take longer than 10 seconds I want to cancel them. After looking at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/494273/) about using [the Python `signal` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) for timeouts, I wrote the following code:

```
#!/my/path/to/sage

import time, signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    errortime = time.time()
    print str(errortime - starttime)[:7]
    raise Exception

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(10)

# Try to do some long computations with Sage
starttime = time.time()
try:
    F.<a> = NumberField(x^31 -5*x^7 +6*x^6 +2*x^5 +4*x^4 +x^3 -3*x^2 -2*x +1)
    result = F.pari_nf()
except Exception:
    print "exception occurred"
finally:
    print result
    signal.alarm(0)
```

which, when run, prints the surprising result

```
18.1582
exception occurred
```

(and it really does take that amount of time, it's not just mismeasuring how long it took)

The computation in the `try` block does usually take about 18 seconds, but shouldn't the `SIGALRM` signal have been raised after **10 seconds**, and `errortime` recorded then? Moreover shouldn't all attempts at doing the computation have stopped once an exception was encountered?

How can I make this Sage script actually stop what it's doing and exit if it takes longer than 10 seconds?

Comment: It doesn't help with how to do this more reliably, but for why it isn't working see the docs you link, third dot point: "signals arriving during long calculations implemented purely in C ... may be delayed for an arbitrary amount of time".

Comment: @lvc: Ah, thanks for catching that - it does seem like that's what's going wrong. As an alternative, do you forsee any problems if I use the Linux command `timeout`, e.g. `timeout 10s ./script.sage`? As far as I can tell by running `top` afterwards, the script doesn't continue running, but I don't know whether there would be other harder-to-notice side effects.

Comment: [the `multiprocessing`-based solution from the thread that you've linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14924210/4279) could be used even if C extension does not return the control to Python interpreter e.g., by calling `PyErr_CheckSignals()` inside C loop.